# bucket directories size limits on MinIO server

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, charts, kubernetes-helm, minio

Is there a way to set quotas for directories inside each bucket in a MinIO server and monitor the size and quota with the API of each directory in the bucket?

Comment: It appears that MinIO has the ability to [set a quota on a bucket](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/reference/minio-mc-admin/mc-admin-bucket-quota.html), but it does not appear to offer that capability at the directory-level.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [this documentation](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/reference/minio-mc-admin/mc-admin-bucket-quota.html#mc-admin-bucket-quota) about bucket quota, but unfortunately it is just for buckets.

> The [`mc  admin  bucket  quota`](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/reference/minio-mc-admin/mc-admin-bucket-quota.html#command-mc.admin.bucket.quota) command manages per-bucket storage quotas.

**NOTE**:

> MinIO does not support using  [`mc  admin`](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/reference/minio-mc-admin.html#command-mc.admin)  commands with other S3-compatible services, regardless of their claimed compatibility with MinIO deployments.

---

Using following command you can get usage info:

```sh
mc du
```

---

See also [this doc](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-admin-complete-guide.html).